# How do I extend ADO.NET Entity Framework objects with partial classes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've created a Visual Basic WPF Application project that contains Toy.edmx, an ADO.NET Entity Data Model generated from a database called Toy.

Its *Window1.xaml.vb* file looks like this:

```
1   Class Window1
2   
3       Private Sub Window1_Loaded( _
4       ByVal sender As System.Object, _
5       ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) _
6       Handles MyBase.Loaded
7   
8           Dim dc As New ToyEntities1
9           Label1.Content = (From c As Client In dc.ClientSet _
10                            Select c).First.FirstName
11  
12      End Sub
13  
14  End Class
```

That runs just fine.

But, if I add the file *Client.vb*...

```
1   Partial Public Class Client
2       Function IsWashington() As Boolean
3           Return Me.LastName = "Washington"
4       End Function
5   End Class
```

...and add a WHERE clause to my *Window1.xaml.vb* query...

```
9           Label1.Content = (From c As Client In dc.ClientSet _
10                            Where c.IsWashington _
11                            Select c).First.FirstName
```

...then I get this NotSupportedException:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsWashington()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How do I extend ADO.NET Entity Framework objects with partial classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing code, and expecting the Entity Framework to translate that into SQL... it can't do that. Just like LINQ to SQL can't do that.

Imagine if your property read a file from the "C:\" drive... how do you think it would handle that? - not possible.

Comment: I hope that didn't sound too harsh... what I should say is that once you're query is "local", you can add your where clause (but that's LINQ to Objects - and that's local, not at the DB level).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do - create a method that applies a filter to Client queries.

I don't know vb.net, so don't trust this free-hand code 100%.

```
Partial Public Class Client
  Public Shared Function IsWashington(query As IQueryable(Of Client)) As IQueryable(Of Client)
    Return query.Where(Function(someClient) someClient.LastName = "Washington")
  End Function
End Class
```

later, some calling code.

```
IQueryable(Of Client) someQuery = dc.ClientSet.AsQueryable
someQuery = Client.IsWashington(someQuery)

Label1.Content = someQuery.First.FirstName
```

Hope this works!

Comment: You can find a blog entry with quite a detailed explanation of the issue here: http://blog.genom-e.com/PermaLink,guid,4c486a95-12ad-4abf-aba1-7eb893c91ba7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What type is Client class?

You might need to add namespace (same as that in which Client "Entity classs" is defined) to the file containing "IsWashington".

Comment: What is wrong with my answer?
How did you resolve the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could work around this particular problem by feeding your Client object from a View.  Use the SQL CASE statement to set a bit column value:

SELECT col1, col2, col3, LastName
CASE LastName
 WHEN 'Washington' THEN 1
 ELSE 0 AS IsWashington
FROM Client

If you use the view as the basis for your Client entity object, the IsWashington column should become a member of the class along with all the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

shahkalpesh is correct, you need to add the namespace around your extended class to match the generated one.